# Sorting Collection<V> and Set<K>

Tags: java

I'm having an issue sorting the values and keys from a map from least to greatest(integers and String's).
Here are the two methods, first the method for values:

```
public Collection<V> values(){
    Collection<V> coll = new LinkedList<V>();
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
        if(table[i] != null){
            for(Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[i]){
                if(nextItem.value != null){
                    if(!coll.contains(nextItem.value)){
                        coll.add(nextItem.value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return coll;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
120 123 404 911 999
```

My Output (basically keeps order of wherever it was in the map):

```
911 999 123 120 404
```

The above method is used with dot notation for a hashTableChain (an array who's keys are sorted by their hashCode where the indices of the array are linkedLists), it returns the values for the given map. I tried sorting it with Collections.sort(coll) however this requires a List which is incompatible with Collection to my knowledge. Is there something compatible with Collection that is either already sorted or can be sorted in an easy way?
The method for the key's:

```
public Set<K> keySet(){
    Set<K> coll = new HashSet<K>();
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
        if(table[i] != null){
            for(Entry<K, V> nextItem : table[i]){
                coll.add(nextItem.key);
            }
        }
    }
    return coll;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
ABC ACTG HTML LOL OMG XYZ
```

My Output (basically keeps order of wherever it was in the map):

```
XYZ ABC ACTG HTML LOL OMG
```

Again I tried Collections.sort(coll) to no avail and couldn't find any way to sort it.

I'm fairly new to java and I'm sure I'm overlooking something, after searching the web for a while I figured I'd just ask.

Thanks in advance and I very much appreciate the help.

Added at request:

```
private static class Entry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {

    /** The key */
    private K key;
    /** The value */
    private V value;

    /**
     * Creates a new key-value pair.
     * @param key The key
     * @param value The value
     */
    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think list is incompatible with collection? It should work with list. What is data type of Values stored in Map?

Comment: The values are a linkedlist made of Entry<K, V>, I tried using List<K>(and T) with Collections<V> = new... and then using Collections.sort(coll) but got an incompatible error. I'm new to Collections so I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

Comment: Can you post your class's member declarations?

Comment: Added the Entry<K,V> bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About first example you can use a `List<V>` for variable `coll`:

```
public Collection<V> values(){
  List<V> coll = new LinkedList<V>();
  // do stuff
  Collections.sort(coll);
  return coll;
}
```

and is correct, because `LinkedList` implements `List`. You have to choice the supertype compatible with your needs; if you need to return a sorted list, you can use a `List` in your function, sort them and return the list as `Collection`.

In second example the same, but use a

```
Set<K> coll = new TreeSet<K>();
```

`TreeSet` implements [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), A Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements.

Comment: Works for keySet() but when I try to use Collections.sort(coll) I get an error saying I can't do this with a List<V>.

Comment: [V must extends Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) else you can use sort(List,Comparator)

Comment: I got it to work with the following: Collections.sort(coll, null);

Comment: It's because V (most probably) is implementing `Comparable` but is not specified in generic siganture. To be correct V should be defined as `V extends Comparable` in contained class. The same for `K`

Comment: This problem was from a textbook and the classes were already mostly written, not sure why the author decided to use K(string) and V(int), would of made it much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

What you call a `Collection` happens to be a `List` in 100% of the cases.  You just need to tell the compiler this by either:

1. Casting `(List<V>)coll` before calling `sort`, or
2. Changing the declaration `List<V> coll= new LinkedList<V>() ;`

If you have `123` as a value two times, I think it's correct it appears two times in `values()`'s result.

In the second case, I'd recommend to use a `SortedSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Please consider the following code:

```
public class Sample<K extends Comparable<K>,V extends Comparable<V>> {

    public static class Entry<A,B> implements Map.Entry<A,B> {
        A key;
        B value;
        public Entry(A key,B value) {
            this.key= key ;
            this.value= value ;
        }
        public A getKey() {
            return this.key ;
        }
        public B getValue() {
            return this.value ;
        }
        public B setValue(B value) {
            return this.value= value ;
        }
    }

    LinkedList<Entry<K,V>>[] table;

    public Collection<V> values(){

        List<V> coll= new LinkedList<V>() ;
        for(LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> e: table ) {
            if( e != null ) {
                for(Entry<K, V> nextItem : e ) {
                    if( nextItem.value != null ) {
                        coll.add(nextItem.value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(coll);
        return coll;
    }
    public Set<K> keySet(){

        Set<K> coll= new TreeSet<K>() ;
        for(LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> e: table ) {
            if( e != null ) {
                for(Entry<K, V> nextItem : e ) {
                    coll.add(nextItem.key);
                }
            }
        }
        return coll;
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {

        Sample<String,Integer> test= new Sample<String,Integer>();
        test.table= (LinkedList<Entry<String,Integer>>[])new LinkedList[1024] ;
        test.table[467]= new LinkedList<Entry<String,Integer>>() ;
        test.table[467].add( new Entry("XYZ",999) ); 
        test.table[467].add( new Entry("ABC",123) ); 
        test.table[678]= new LinkedList<Entry<String,Integer>>() ;
        test.table[678].add( new Entry("ACTG",404) ); 
        test.table[678].add( new Entry("HTML",120) ); 
        test.table[678].add( new Entry("ACTG",404) ); 
        test.table[678].add( new Entry("LOL",123) ); 
        test.table[  2]= new LinkedList<Entry<String,Integer>>() ;
        test.table[  2].add( new Entry("OMG",911) );

        System.out.println( test.values() );
        System.out.println( test.keySet() );
    }
}
```

If you expect to create a generic class in which the values of the parametric types are going to be sorted, then they need to implement interface `Comparable`.  And if they need to implement interface `Comparable`, then you need to say so when declaring your class.  That's why the `K extends Comparable<K>` and `V extends Comparable<V>` while declaring `Sample`.  This is particularly important when you call `Collections.sort` or you instantiate `TreeSet`.  Both require that the parameters/parametric types are `Comparable`s (or subtypes of).

The result of the test case I added are correct:

```
[120, 123, 123, 404, 404, 911, 999]
[ABC, ACTG, HTML, LOL, OMG, XYZ]
```

respectively.

Comment: How would I use addAll() when the method isn't passed anything? I'm also getting an error saying that List<V> is not compatible with Collections(The inferred type V is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>)

Comment: To my understanding, Map.Entry<K,V> (the class being extending) does implement comparable, and is not overridden so should still be in effect.

Comment: @Kerher Suppressed that comment, as I realized you were not talking about a regular `LinkedList` but your own implementation.  Hope I figured out your class's members correctly.  I explained your second point in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Kerher  That's incorrect.  The parameter types of an inner class are independent of the parameter types of the outer class.  The `K` and `V ` in `Entry` are completely different to the `K` and `V` in `Map`.  In fact, I'll change the code to use `A` and `B`, and you'll see that nothing changes.

Comment: @Kerher  Additionally, `Map.Entry<K,V>` does not impose any constraint in `K` or `V`.  Neither does `Map<K,V>`.  Why would them if they are supposed to work with all kind of objects?  Different thing is subclasses like `TreeMap`.  But this is another story.

Comment: @Kerher  I added a small test case to the code I had provided previously, and it works 100% as expected.